# how to create an java editor in a web page

Tags: java, web, editor, codemirror

I am creating a web portal and database to teach students how to program.

I want to have a editor on the page so that the students can see what they are doing if you know what I mean.

I can do basic HTML but trying to do an editor is bit advanced for me which I am willing to learn.

What is the best way of going about it I have heard of codemirror but not sure how to use it.

Many Thanks

Comment: Since it is for educational purposes, you may use [Sphere Engine](http://sphere-research.com/products.html) under Educational Initiatives. Sphere Engine is well known for supporting [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/). DISCLAIMER: I'm not attached nor linked to Sphere Research economically, just did a search on ideone tool and came up to that link.

Comment: CodeMirror has a website. That website has documentation — http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by looking at [the documentation](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html) and especially at the code from this example: http://codemirror.net/mode/clike/index.html

The code to create the editor is pretty simple. You need a text area with an `id`:

```
<textarea id="java-code"></textarea>
```

and this JavaScript to create the editor:

```
  var javaEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("java-code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/x-java"
  });
  var mac = CodeMirror.keyMap.default == CodeMirror.keyMap.macDefault;
  CodeMirror.keyMap.default[(mac ? "Cmd" : "Ctrl") + "-Space"] = "autocomplete";
```